# 16 gb ram upgrade beneficial for photoshop?

Tags: memory

i have a lenovo computer (https://share.rtechsupport.org/files/8xdNnh1BEdOO_Sketch.png). i work usually with 5 tabs open in chrome, itunes always runnin, and photoshop and other application running. Do you think i will benefit from upgrading my ram from 8gb to 16gb. Thanks. NOTE- photoshop barely works. There is a 2 sec lag almost always. That's why i have to use sketchbook pro

Answer (score 2):

The 16GB will help a bit, but you'd be better off with 16GB **and** a SSD.
Seriously, a SSD is probably the best upgrade investment you can make.

Executive summary: Give it a SSD and 16GB RAM - this will not only be "beneficial", it will leverage your user experience to a completely different (higher) performance level.